# Is there a rectangular pyramid whose altitude, slant height, and ALL edge lengths are all integers, or rationals?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers, pythagorean-triples

f so, have any suggestions on methods to find all such pyramids?

but besides guess-and-check don't know where to begin.

Background: I am a high school math teacher and got curious about this when generating problems. Not a homework set for me.

Comment: Maybe try looking if integer triangles can be glued to build a pyramid with integer altitude. For example, there are [Pythagorean triangles with integer altitude from the hypotenuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_triangle#Pythagorean_triangles_with_integer_altitude_from_the_hypotenuse).

Comment: When I'm understanding "slant height(s)" correctly there are two of them in a rectangular pyramid.

Comment: I'm sure they exist but I have failed to find one yet in 11 years of research on finding Pythagorean triples. I did not focus on it but tried as a side-thing when I discovered it is easy to find triangular tiles and pyramids composed of 6 non-identical primitive triples each. If you would like to see my paper on the subject, send me an email poetasis@gmail.com

Comment: If you wish, I can also show you the code I used to find quadrilateral tiles and pyramids. I was looking for tiles so I did not measure altitude.

Comment: @Eod J. thanks! good wiki

Comment: @ChristianBlatter yes, should have said "slant heights" (using the term to mean the distance from the apex of pyramid to the the base edges)

Comment: @poetasis very interesting-- thanks! I emailed you.

Answer (score 4):

It is an old mathematical problem to find [*Euler bricks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick), or *perfect cuboids*. These are orthogonal boxes with $6$ or $7$ integer side lengths, face diagonals, and body diagonals. A perfect cuboid ($7$ integer lengths) has not yet been found, nor excluded, but there are almost perfect cuboids with $6$ integer lengths. Among them the cuboid with side lengths  $104$, $153$, $672$, face diagonals $\sqrt{104^2+153^2}=185$, $\sqrt{104^2+672^2}= 680$, $\sqrt{474993}$, and body diagonal $697$.

Since there is no requirement about the base diagonal in the pyramid we can use this cuboid to construct a pyramid of the required kind: Take a base rectangle with side lengths $2\cdot153=306$ and $2\cdot672=1344$. In the center of this rectangle erect a height $104$ to the peak of the pyramid. The slant heights  then are $185$ and $680$, and the  edges going to the peak have length $\sqrt{153^2+672^2+104^2}=697$.

[image]